# Looping through a .txt files then rewrite them in different names

Tags: matlab

I am just trying to read different .txt files from a directory e.g. B1.txt...Bn.txt then I want to rescale the values of each .txt file and rewrite them different .txt files in form BF1.txt,...BFn.txt. I was able to read the files using the following snippet code but couldn't rewrite them. Here is my attempt;

```
NoOFfiles = 4;
for k = 1:NoOFfiles 
filename = sprintf('B%d.txt',k);
A = load(filename)./1000; 
 end
```

Any help,

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Typical usage would be for `load` to be used when loading a `.mat` file, not a text file (although as you've found it can be used to read `ascii` files).  Depending on the format of the file you most likely want to use either the `dlmread`/`dlmwrite` or `csvread`/`csvwrite` pairs, or the more modern `readtable`/`writetable` pair.

Comment: Can we see a snippet of a typical fine content?

Comment: a snippet would be great!

Comment: Indeed, it would be great. He's asking *you* for a snippet so we can understand the structure of the files, because it can change the answer drastically.